# Libgdx Animation wrong position with correct coordinates

Tags: animation, libgdx, isometric

Im trying to make a isometric videogame in Libgdx and when Im programming the animations I have a strange error.

I have two 3 tiles in the scene: static body without animation, tile floor and body with animation.

All have the same coordinates and the static body wihout animation and tile floor are in the same position but the body with animation are in wrong position.

Here a image, all in the image are in the same scene at the same time:

[Image from scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV0eC.png)

Static body is a frame from Spritesheet of the animation.

Here is my relevant code:

```
    TextureAtlas texureAtlasHair;
    Animation<TextureRegion> animationHairHeroRunning;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    texureAtlasHair = new TextureAtlas("hero/ClothesBueno/ClothesB.atlas");
    animationHairHeroRunning = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1f/4f,texureAtlasHair.findRegions("Stance"));

    heroLoad = new Texture("map/Stance_1.png");
    heroLoadSprite = new Sprite(heroLoad);
    heroLoadSprite.flip(false,true);

    public void render() {

      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      batch.setProjectionMatrix(dungeonCam.combined);
      dungeonCam.update();
      batch.begin();

      elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

      //FloorTile
      Vector2 pointFloor = twoDToIso(new Vector2(25,30));
      batch.draw(floor,pointFloor.x,pointFloor.y);

      //Hero without animation
      Vector2 pointHero = twoDToIso(new Vector2(25,30));
      batch.draw(heroLoadSprite,pointHero.x,pointHero.y);

      //Hero with animation
      TextureRegion currentFrameHair = 
      animationHairHeroRunning.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime,true);
      batch.draw(currentFrameHair,pointHero.x,pointHero.y,128,-128);

      batch.end();
    }


    public Vector2 twoDToIso(Vector2 punto) {
      Vector2 tempP = new Vector2(0, 0);
      tempP.x = (punto.x - punto.y) * 32;
      tempP.y = (punto.x + punto.y) * 16;
      return tempP;
    }
```

Edit

[AtlasImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40A27.png)

And my .atlas is like this.

[.atlas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9ytM.png)

And my actual code to AtlasRegions:

```
Array<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion> arrayRegions;

texureAtlasHair = new TextureAtlas("hero/ClothesBueno/ClothesB.atlas");
arrayRegions = texureAtlasHair.findRegions("Stance");
animationHairHeroRunning = new Animation(1f/4f,arrayRegions);
```

Comment: If you used whitespace stripping when you packed your atlas, you need to be getting AtlasRegions from your atlas, not dumbing them down to TextureRegions. You need to add atlasRegion.offsetX and Y to the position that you draw it.

Comment: Can you see my edit post? Because I have atlas with the frames but all have offset 0 and in my batch.draw how can I draw that offset?

Comment: Is there a reason you're drawing your animation with negative height?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Im making a isometric game then I need flip all my textures and animations.